# prove that $18^n-n^{16}$ is divisible by $17$ for any natural $n$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

prove that

$18^n-n^{16}$ is divisible by $17$ for any natural $n$.

I have tried using Fermat's small theorem so far and got nowhere as I get contradiction for the case $n=17$ either way and for any case $n\neq16k$ I have no clue what to do with it.

Comment: Well, you can't do it if it's false. It's true when $n$ is not divisible by $17$ though.

Comment: Any reason why you have typed $16$ in a weird, hard to read way?

Comment: yes, i realize it works for n≠17k, but how do i prove this

Comment: @DeltaAccount You already wrote that you should use Fermat's little theorem, so just try it. Check what $18^n$ and $n^{16}$ are equal to mod $n$.

Comment: because I couldn't use $s to indicate the power of two digit nums

Comment: Yes you can. `a^{bc}` renders $a^{bc}$.

Comment: Isn't it "Fermat's Little Theorem", as a play on "Fermat's Last Theorem"?

Comment: What are $18^n-1$ and $n^{16}-1$ modulo $17$?

Comment: The proof when $\,17\nmid n\,$ is an immediate consequence of the linked congruence laws, i.e. $18\equiv 1\Rightarrow 18^n\equiv 1^n\equiv 1,\,$ and $\,n\not\equiv 0\Rightarrow n^{16}\equiv 1\,$ by Fermat.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As someone mentioned, this is true when **n is not divisible by 17**!
So in that case, we need to look at this whole equation mod 17, and we will prove it is equal to 0.
First, $$18^n - n^{16} \mod{17} = (18 \mod{17})^n - (n \mod{17})^{16} \\= 1^n-n^{16} \mod17 = 1 - n^{16} \mod17 $$
so no we just need to show that for any $n$ which is not divisible by 17  ( $n \neq 0)  \mod17)$), the following equality holds:
$$ n^{16} = 1 \mod17$$
And because 17 is **prime**, such $n$ is invertible, and we can use the Fermat little theorem which says that $n^17 = n \mod17$ and get that
$$n^{16} = n^{17} * n_{-1} = n * n^{-1} = 1 \mod17$$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).  Please delete the answer so that the dupe can be more easily cleaned up.

Comment: @BillDubuque But how is this question a duplicate of that other question in the link? Not only it's not the same problem, the other question doesn't even deal with division by $17$. Not sure how reading the answers there will help OP solve this problem. (I hope OP already solved it anyway)

Comment: @Mark See my [closure comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4789399/prove-that-18n-n16-is-divisible-by-17-for-any-natural-n/4789415?noredirect=1#comment10182644_4789399) and see [abstract duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1756/242).